# Unexpected red border (validation error) on DataGrid when selecting blank row

Tags: wpf, validation, data-binding, mvvm

When I select (by clicking or by keyboard) blank row on my DataGrid (when I want to add new row), unexpected validation error occurs (but with no exception) - the border of datagrid changes to red color, as you can see on the image below. When I click second time on blank row, the red border dissapears. Everything other works fine, the new row is added. Besides, I don't have any validation rules. And when I make a row with empty text, value is valid.

I don't want this behavior and this red border, anybody knows, why this happens and how to fix it? Why and where some validation fails?

[image]

Below I append some source code:

DataGrid definition in xaml:

```
    <DataGrid IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ConfigFiles}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedConfigFile}" 
              Grid.Column="1" Height="87" Margin="0,26,11,32" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

My ViewModel's part:

```
public class ManageModulesVM : BaseVM  // Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...

    public ObservableCollection<ConfigFile> ConfigFiles
    {
        get { return selectedModule == null ? null : selectedModule.ConfigFiles; }
        set
        {
            selectedModule.ConfigFiles = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => ConfigFiles);
        }
    }

    public ConfigFile SelectedConfigFile
    {
        get { return selectedModule == null ? null : selectedModule.SelectedConfigFile; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                selectedModule.SelectedConfigFile = value;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedConfigFile);
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Parameters);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

ConfigFile class:

```
public class ConfigFile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }

    public ConfigFile() { Name = ""; Parameters = new List<Parameter>(); }
}
```

Edit:
After further investigation I know, that SelectedItem Binding is causing problems (when I remove this binding, validation error stops to appear), but I still don't know why and how to fix this.

Comment: I don't know that this is your problem but you have dual references to binding to Name.  I would remove the DisplayMemberPath.  You can also attached a pass thru converter (string to string) on name and that way you can catch the Exception.  And I would explicitly put mode = twoway on the binding.

Comment: @BalamBalam good point, It didn't solve my problem, but was helpful too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've found my own solution to this question. I've written a value converter and tied it to the binding:

`(SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedConfigFile,Converter={StaticResource configFileConverter}}")`

The converter class:

```
namespace Converters
{
    public class SelectedConfigFileConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(value is ConfigFile)
                return value;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Define resource in `resources.xaml` file (or in any other resources place):

```
<ResourceDictionary (...) xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Converters" >
    <conv:SelectedConfigFileConverter x:Key="configFileConverter" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The advantage of this solution is that the `SelectedConfigFile` property's type did't changed (to the general `object` type) so it is still strongly typed.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer, as it is a more correct solution.  See http://blog.spencen.com/2009/04/30/problems-binding-to-selectedvalue-with-microsoftrsquos-wpf-datagrid.aspx for a similar solution.

Answer (score 11):

To get the reason, when you click the new row of DataGrid in Debug mode, please see the debug window. There are first exception messages which will give you the idea why your problem is occurred.

Yes, the problem is from type casting. You need to modify the type of SelectedItem to object type as below.

```
public class ManageModulesVM : BaseVM  // Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...

    public object SelectedConfigFile
    {
        get { return selectedModule == null ? null : selectedModule.SelectedConfigFile; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                selectedModule.SelectedConfigFile = value;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedConfigFile);
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Parameters);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) And yes, there was exception (Cannot convert '{NewItemPlaceholder}' from type 'NamedObject' to type 'ConfigFile')  in visual studio's debug output window, I'm new to WPF, I did't know that such valuable informations are written there.

Comment: This post is really about _how to debug_ rather than _suggesting a solution_ for the OP.  Please see **Łukasz Wiatrak** marked answer above.

Comment: @MickyDuncan Yes, you may be right, but as you can see, my answer shows basic solution, which would let @Łukasz Wiatrak create `SelectedConfigFileConverter`. It is free that you can think @Łukasz Wiatrak's answer is better but I cannot agree "This post is really about how to debug rather than suggesting a solution for the OP" because I showed the solution above to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Jin-WookChung Not only is your VM not type-safe it **contains a bug which will lead to a crash**.  Furthermore, your claim that your "basic solution" would miracoulsy lead the OP to create a **SelectedConfigFileConverter** is without evidence.  You don't even mention **IValueConverter**

Answer (score 6):

Here's a general-purpose converter you can use for any DataGrid, binding any kind of item:

```
    public class DataGridItemConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
    static DataGridItemConverter converter;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
        return value;
        }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
        return (value != null && value.GetType() == targetType) ? value : null;
        }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
        if (converter == null)
            converter = new DataGridItemConverter();
        return converter;
        }
    }
```

Since it implements MarkupExtension you don't even need to define a static resource, you can just reference it like this:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedThing,Converter={conv:DataGridItemConverter}}"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just add this line to your DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" />
```

Comment: this not a good  solution because will remove validation template ,so how we can custom the validation?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add this line to your DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" />
```

It will solve the problem

Comment: Never a good idea to supress errors to get rid of them, it can cause debugging nightmares in the future. Find the cause of the error and fix it.