# Get error 23 and error 7 when selecting Datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Working in WPf, C# and using MVVM-C I have the following error in the Immediate window in VS.

The window I’m talking about is filled with some textboxes and a datagrid where the user can add new rows. When filling in the textboxes, no problem is shown. 
Due to this problem I’m not able to save the changes. In fact, the Save button won't work.

But as soon as I'm clicking on the empty datagrid to be able to add some data, I receive following errors in the immediate window:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert '{NewItemPlaceholder}' from type 'NamedObject' to type 'LIMS.ViewModels.ComponentViewModel' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter kan niet van MS.Internal.NamedObject worden geconverteerd.
- bij System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
- bij System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
- bij MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)'

System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '{NewItemPlaceholder}' (type 'NamedObject'). BindingExpression:Path=SelectedTestConfiguration.SelectedComponent; DataItem='TestConfigurationsPageViewModel' (HashCode=64210551); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter kan niet van MS.Internal.NamedObject worden geconverteerd.
- bij MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
- bij MS.Internal.Data.ObjectTargetConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
- bij System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

A screen shot of the program:

[image: screen]

Every page exists of a

- Pagecontroller
- PageViewModel
- PageResources (xaml- code)

Any ideas? I also don’t know which code you need to see the source of the problem.

Extract of Xaml Code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TestConfigurationsDataTemplate"
          DataType="{x:Type testconfigurations:TestConfigurationsPageViewModel}">

    <Grid Grid.Row="3"
          Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Components" Style="{StaticResource RegularTextLeft}"/>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTestConfiguration.Components}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTestConfiguration.SelectedComponent}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="True"
              Margin="{StaticResource SmallMargin}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cell" Binding="{Binding Cell}"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="PerformCalculation" Binding="{Binding PerformCalculation}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Calculation" Binding="{Binding Calculation}"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Input Result" Binding="{Binding InputResult}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>


    <Button Grid.Row="5"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Content="Save TestConfiguration"
            Command="{Binding SaveTestConfigurationCommand}"/>
```

Extract of PageViewModel

```
public class TestConfigurationsPageViewModel:PageViewModel
{
    private Command _searchCommand;
    public Command SearchCommand
    {
        get { return _searchCommand; }
        set
        {
            if (_searchCommand != value)
            {
                _searchCommand = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchCommand);
            }
        }
    }

    private Command _addTestConfigurationCommand;
    public Command AddTestConfigurationCommand
    {
        get { return _addTestConfigurationCommand; }
        set
        {
            if (_addTestConfigurationCommand != value)
            {
                _addTestConfigurationCommand = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => AddTestConfigurationCommand);
            }
        }
    }

    private Command _saveTestConfigurationCommand;
    public Command SaveTestConfigurationCommand
    {
        get { return _saveTestConfigurationCommand; }
        set
        {
            if (_saveTestConfigurationCommand != value)
            {
                _saveTestConfigurationCommand = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SaveTestConfigurationCommand);
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableItemsCollection<TestConfigurationViewModel> _testconfigurations;
    public ObservableItemsCollection<TestConfigurationViewModel> Testconfigurations
    {
        get { return _testconfigurations; }
        set
        {
            if (_testconfigurations != value)
            {
                _testconfigurations = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Testconfigurations);
            }
        }
    }

    private TestConfigurationViewModel _selectedTestConfiguration;
    public TestConfigurationViewModel SelectedTestConfiguration
    {
        get { return _selectedTestConfiguration; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedTestConfiguration != value)
            {
                RaisePropertyChanging(() => SelectedTestConfiguration);
                _selectedTestConfiguration = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedTestConfiguration);
            }
        }
    }

    private string _searchExpression;
    public string SearchExpression
    {
        get { return _searchExpression; }
        set
        {
            if (_searchExpression != value)
            {
                _searchExpression = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchExpression);
            }
        }
    }

    public TestConfigurationsPageViewModel()
    {
        Testconfigurations = new ObservableItemsCollection<TestConfigurationViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the XAML code where you bind the datagrid items, along with the properties you're binding to.

Comment: Thx for your reply, i added the needed code. An extract from the xaml and the properties fo the PageViewModel

Comment: Does the type of `SelectedTestConfiguration.SelectedComponent` have a default constructor? Otherwise it seems that WPF can't directly cast that type at runtime, I'd try to add a converter similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7702129/368354

Comment: @Deschuytterp There's no answer listed but the solution was in the article pointed to by Lennart (though the URL is now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697973/unexpected-red-border-validation-error-on-datagrid-when-selecting-blank-row/7702129#7702129).  Lennart should be given the Answer credit.

Answer (score 0):

Credits for this answer rather to to https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42548/MVVM-and-the-WPF-DataGrid, but here's the summary with regards to your observation.

The problem is that your DataGrid has the CanUserAddRows set to True and the SelectedItem being bound to some non-string property of your VM. The new empty row has an internal string value of "{NewItemPlaceHolder}". That won't fit together. The workaround is to put an appropriate placeholder in charge, like so:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:IgnoreNewItemPlaceHolderConverter x:Key="IgnoreNewItemPlaceHolderConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGrid.SelectedItem>
        <Binding Converter="{StaticResource IgnoreNewItemPlaceHolderConverter}" Path="MySelectedItem" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </DataGrid.SelectedItem>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

and

```
internal class IgnoreNewItemPlaceHolderConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private const string NewItemPlaceholderName = "{NewItemPlaceholder}";
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value.ToString() == NewItemPlaceholderName)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        return value;
    }
}
```