# Using a IConverter to deal with {NewItemPlaceholder} in WPF / XAML / MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Here is my DataTemplate:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converter:PlaceholderConverter x:Key="_placeholderConverter"/>

    <!-- Data(Display)Template for data objects of x:Type Customer-->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Customer}">
        <!-- Customer Properties will be vertically stacked -->
        <ContentControl >
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phone}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
<UserControl.Resources>
```

And the two different 'container's:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0"
            Content="Delete"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="75"
            Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>

    <ListBox 
        Grid.Row="2" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Customers, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

And the app:

[image]

1. How to remove the {NewItemPlaceholder}? [Done, solution below].
2. How to prevent the binding error that mention "{NewItemPlaceholder}" when clicking in one of the empty rows in the table above intending on adding a new row (I can still add rows).

The errors:

```
...Cannot convert '{NewItemPlaceholder}' from type 'NamedObject' to type 'CustomerExample.Model.Customer'...


...ConvertBack cannot convert value '{NewItemPlaceholder}' (type 'NamedObject'). BindingExpression:Path=SelectedCustomer; DataItem='CustomerViewModel'...
```

I can write an IConverter implementation, but how to tie it in to the XAML?

thanks in advance :-)

Here is the implementation of the IConverter:

```
public class PlaceholderConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value.ToString() == "{NewItemPlaceholder}")
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and to bind to individual items, the XAML goes something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource PlaceholderConverter}}"/>
```

But I think I need to add it 'globally' to the data collection elements, not to where individual properties are being bound.

Comment: I assume you want to add new rows ?

Comment: yes @Blacktempel... I just don't know where I can bind the converter. (The bottom display is readonly.)

Comment: I don't see any `IConverter` used in your code... Could you provide more details on how you use it?

Comment: @Grx70 ... there's your IConverter. I just don't know were to put the     `, Converter={StaticResource PlaceholderConverter}`.

Comment: As a note, the ContentControl in the Customer DataTemplate is redundant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validation error on DataGrid when selecting blank row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697973/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need a Binding Converter. Instead, bind the ListBox to a `CollectionViewSource` that wraps the Custumers collection. The CollectionViewSource skips the NewItemPlaceholder element from the source collection.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    ...
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CustomersCVS" Source="{Binding Customers}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

...
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomersCVS}}"/>
```

---

You also don't need a Converter for the SelectedItem Binding. Just set the Binding's `TargetNullValue` property:

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer,
    TargetNullValue={x:Static CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder}}" .../>
```

Answer (score -1):

Even though the accepted answer is correct for the OP's question I needed a more general approach to prevent the error and still allow users to add rows. As I used this ValueConverter for many different object types I used reflection to determine the target type's constructor and just returned a new object of that type.

```
public class IgnoreNewItemPlaceHolderConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private const string NewItemPlaceholderName = "{NewItemPlaceholder}";
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        return value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value.ToString() == NewItemPlaceholderName)
        {
            var ctors = targetType.GetConstructors();

            // invoke the first public constructor with no parameters.
            return ctors[0].Invoke(new object[] { });
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```